# What does the phrase "tight level design" mean here?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, phrases

I am not sure about the meaning of the phrase "tight level design" in the following [sentence](https://www.origin.com/ind/en-us/store/battlefield/battlefield-3/expansion/battlefield-3-close-quarters) from a combat game's description:

> The **tight level design** and many opportunities for vertical gameplay
>   mean players will need to bring their A game if they want to stay
>   alive in this highly competitive theater of war.

I know the lexical meanings of the word [tight](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tight), but cannot figure out which of them suits here.

Answer (score 1):

Tight here would be some variation of meaning 1 in the dictionary you linked to. The arena the game takes place is not large and wide open but instead is smaller and confined, with players located close together.

Comment: I think there is probably also an aspect of meaning 5: tight in the sense of careful, precise, having nothing extraneous.